# Convert layout to class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I currently have a layout that has scrollviewer as main layout, and a relative one (with a lot of views) as my app layout, but now I need to make tabs, the android tutorial instructs to make the actual layout of each tab programatically, how do I convert my current layout (xml) to a class? Is there any guideline to follow? how do I set the relative layout inside the scrollviewer and how do I specify the "android:layout_below="SOMETHING"" and all that properties?

Answer (score 0):

I din't understand your question very well but, when creating the TabLayout programaticaly you define the activities that are used for each of the tabs. Each of them should have setContentView( 'activity layout')

Comment: What I meant is how should I convert an already defined XML layout (one that has nested views and widgets) to a class, in order to define the controlls of each tab programatically.

Comment: Hmm, just create a simple activity that holds your xml layout, then create the Tab using that acitivity! `code` intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NEWACTIVITYCLASS.class);
  spec = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("NAMEOFTAB")
    .setIndicator(res.getText(TEXT ID),
      res.getDrawable(ICON))
    .setContent(intent);

Comment: Yeah I know, but my question is, do I have to convert manually my XML layout that I alreadu have to be a NEWACTIVITYCLASS.class? or could I specify in the NEWACTIVITYCLASS.class that the layout is an actual layout.xml besides the main one that contains all the tabhost code.

Comment: Just specify the existing layout on the NewActivity.class :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to access XML elements in Android you need to do something like the following:

```
Button submitButton = (Button) myActivity.getViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
```

Then you can call things like submitButton.setVisibility(View.HIDDEN) to hide it, or whatever else you need to do with it.

This should work for any layout elements.

Make sure you do this in your onActivityStart method, or else you will throw runtime exceptions.

There isn't any way to automatically "convert" an XML layout file to a class, unless you're using an XML parsing algorithm of some sort, which sounds like way more than you're trying to do.

Hope this helped!